# How to get different element of a list evertime to set as an increment so I can edit another lists elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was assigned to edit a simple ROT13 code, however, instead of setting the increment as the number 13, I am trying to set the increment as the number of characters in each word.

For example; if the plain text is " I love you too"
Then, every word has to have its own increment since the word " love " should become " pszi " because every letter should be incremented by 4 because the word has 4 letters itself. Also, the word "you" should become "brx" because it has an increment of 3 since the word has 3 letters.

```
import  sys

# Dictionary to lookup the index of alphabets
alphabet = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'E' : 5,
        'F' : 6, 'G' : 7, 'H' : 8, 'I' : 9, 'J' : 10,
        'K' : 11, 'L' : 12, 'M' : 13, 'N' : 14, 'O' : 15,
        'P' : 16, 'Q' : 17, 'R' : 18, 'S' : 19, 'T' : 20,
        'U' : 21, 'V' : 22, 'W' : 23, 'X' : 24, 'Y' : 25, 'Z' : 26}

# Dictionary to lookup alphabets corresponding to the index after inc
enchabet = {0 : 'Z', 1 : 'A', 2 : 'B', 3 : 'C', 4 : 'D', 5 : 'E',
        6 : 'F', 7 : 'G', 8 : 'H', 9 : 'I', 10 : 'J',
        11 : 'K', 12 : 'L', 13 : 'M', 14 : 'N', 15 : 'O',
        16 : 'P', 17 : 'Q', 18 : 'R', 19 : 'S', 20 : 'T',
        21 : 'U', 22 : 'V', 23 : 'W', 24 : 'X', 25 : 'Y'}

# Function to rotLPWen the string
# according to the inc provided
def rotLPWen(msg, inc):
    calc = ''
    for char in msg:
        # checking for space
        if(char != ' '):
            # looks up the dictionary and
            # adds the inc to the index
            num = ( alphabet[char] + inc ) % 26
            # looks up the second dictionary for
            # the inced alphabets and adds them
            calc += enchabet[num]
        else:
            # adds space
            calc += ' '
            #print("You can only type one word at a time!")
            #sys.exit(1)

    return calc

# Function to rotLPWde the string
# according to the inc provided
def rotLPWde(msg, inc):
    calced = ''
    for char in msg:
        # checks for space
        if(char != ' '):
            # looks up the dictionary and
            # subtracts the inc to the index
            num = ( alphabet[char] - inc + 26) % 26
            # looks up the second dictionary for the
            # inced alphabets and adds them
            calced += enchabet[num]
        else:
            # adds space
            calced += ' '
            #print("You can only type one word at a time!")
            #sys.exit(1)
    return calced

# driver function to run the program
def main():
    # use 'upper()' function to convert any lowercase characters to uppercase
    msg = input("Plase type something!")
    # Create an increment for the number of characters in the sentence
    increment = len(msg)
    inc = increment
    result = rotLPWen(msg.upper(), inc)

#Creates a list from the sentence
    #list1 = list(map(len,msg.split()))
    print(result)
    print(increment)
# Executes the main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At this point, I am able to change the increment by the number of characters in the sentence, but not the words individually. I tried printing the words one by one encrypting them individually and printing them as one sentence but I was not able to get them out of the list one by one while assigning the necessary increment to them. I was thinking if could I set a list that has
" `[I] [love] [you] [too]` " and combine it with another list such as `list1 = list(map)len, msg.split()))` which should look like [1, 4, 3, 3] but I was not able to combine them together since one element has to become the integer for another element from another list.

Comment: There is no question in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. I suspect your problem is nothing to do with ROT13. Get rid of as much code as you can to focus on the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code and added the functionality to increment the alphabets of each word by the length of the word.

Now, if the input message is a sentence, it splits it into a list of words and encodes each word individually, and constructs the encoded sentence at the end.

On the other hand, if the input if a single word, it simple encodes it without creating a list.

```
import  sys

# Dictionary to lookup the index of alphabets
alphabet = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'E' : 5,
        'F' : 6, 'G' : 7, 'H' : 8, 'I' : 9, 'J' : 10,
        'K' : 11, 'L' : 12, 'M' : 13, 'N' : 14, 'O' : 15,
        'P' : 16, 'Q' : 17, 'R' : 18, 'S' : 19, 'T' : 20,
        'U' : 21, 'V' : 22, 'W' : 23, 'X' : 24, 'Y' : 25, 'Z' : 26}

# Dictionary to lookup alphabets corresponding to the index after inc
enchabet = {0 : 'Z', 1 : 'A', 2 : 'B', 3 : 'C', 4 : 'D', 5 : 'E',
        6 : 'F', 7 : 'G', 8 : 'H', 9 : 'I', 10 : 'J',
        11 : 'K', 12 : 'L', 13 : 'M', 14 : 'N', 15 : 'O',
        16 : 'P', 17 : 'Q', 18 : 'R', 19 : 'S', 20 : 'T',
        21 : 'U', 22 : 'V', 23 : 'W', 24 : 'X', 25 : 'Y'}

# Function to rotLPWen the string
# according to the inc provided
def rotLPWen(msg, inc):
    calc = ''
    for char in msg:
        # checking for space
        if(char != ' '):
            # looks up the dictionary and
            # adds the inc to the index
            num = ( alphabet[char] + inc ) % 26
            # looks up the second dictionary for
            # the inced alphabets and adds them
            calc += enchabet[num]
        else:
            # adds space
            calc += ' '
            #print("You can only type one word at a time!")
            #sys.exit(1)

    return calc

# Function to rotLPWde the string
# according to the inc provided
def rotLPWde(msg, inc):
    calced = ''
    for char in msg:
        # checks for space
        if(char != ' '):
            # looks up the dictionary and
            # subtracts the inc to the index
            num = ( alphabet[char] - inc + 26) % 26
            # looks up the second dictionary for the
            # inced alphabets and adds them
            calced += enchabet[num]
        else:
            # adds space
            calced += ' '
            #print("You can only type one word at a time!")
            #sys.exit(1)
    return calced

# driver function to run the program
def main():
    # use 'upper()' function to convert any lowercase characters to uppercase
    msg = input("Plase type something!")
    msg = msg.strip()
    if ' ' in msg.strip():
      words = msg.split(' ')      
    
      encrypted = ''
      increments = []
      for word in words:
      # Create an increment for the number of characters in the sentence
        increment = len(word)
        inc = increment
        result = rotLPWen(word.upper(), inc)
        encrypted += result + ' '
        increments.append(inc)
    
    else:
      increments = len(msg)
      inc = increments
      encrypted = rotLPWen(msg.upper(), inc)       


#Creates a list from the sentence
    #list1 = list(map(len,msg.split()))
    print(encrypted)
    print(increments)
# Executes the main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Plase type something! I love you too   
J PSZI BRX WRR 
[1, 4, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.

```
def rotation_decoder (encoded_string: str, rotation_key: int) -> str :
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    rotation = alphabet [rotation_key:] + alphabet [:rotation_key]
    translation_table = encoded_string.maketrans (alphabet, rotation)
    return encoded_string.translate (translation_table)

decoded_sentence = ''
sentence = 'i love you too'
words = sentence.split (' ')
for word in words :
    decoded_word = rotation_decoder (word, len (word))
    decoded_sentence += decoded_word + ' '

print (decoded_sentence)
```